# Vertex and Fragment Shader worldNormal

Tags: opengl, shaders, glsl, hlsl, fragment-shader

How to access/calculate worldNormal in a Vertex and Fragment shader ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply the normal with the worldmatrix, not the world_view_projection.

do this in the vertex shader, and then pass the value down as a linear interpolation value.
then you dont need to do it in the pixelshader.

Comment: Like this ? `o.WorldNormal = normalize( mul(float4(v.normal, 0.0), _Object2World).xyz);`

Comment: Yes, that looks correct.